React native AAPT: error: resource drawable/material_ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp
am getting react native android build issue in windows with kind of this error
ERROR:C:\Users\userme\myapp\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\developmentRelease\mergeDevelopmentReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1984: AAPT: error: resource drawable/material_ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp (aka com.myapp.development:drawable/material_ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp) not found.
i tried :

clean build folder
remove / install packages
clean gradle cache
sync files from android studio

RN : 0.72
java : 17
node : 20.17.0
regarding that i tried on another windows machine and the build works fine (same env config) , only on one of our engineers laptop we have this issue.
any suggestions please

This question is similar to: AAPT error: resource drawable/... not found. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

yeah its different i will update it with how exactly it looks , the issue here is that this files are not found anywhere i don't even know from where they came up and its the build files which are reporting as missing files which made the debug crazy
